# Check if cookie exists then extract value

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, web

I have looked around for a while now and i cannot find a solution that suits me.

I am trying to check if a cookie exists, and if it does, get the contents from it and take you the URL it contains.

I created my cookie like this:

```
<script>
document.cookie = "pin=<?php echo $_GET['pin']; ?>"
</script>
```

pretending $_GET["pin"]=5060; it should create the cookie pin=5060

I now need something that checks if it exists (this would be on a different page)

if the cookie exists, it should extract the value of the pin then it should take you to:
http://musicdemo.hol.es/users/**(value of pin here)**/host.php?pin=**(value of pin here again)**

this pin is not a password and it does not need to be secured.

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: I smell security issues.

Comment: Why not do this in PHP, where you have a much more consise and usable way to access cookies

Comment: Why do you use PHP code to generate JavaScript code to create a cookie? You can create cookies with either languages.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't understand properly the JS cookie**s**. There are no cookies. The document stack in one attribute named cookie a String with all the cookies. So, you shall split that string to catch'em. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/document.cookie) for more info.

About the condition. Every time you check if `document.cookie` exists it will return true. Because that attribute is *built-it* on the document. So, try to check if can split it or if the size is greater than 0.

And, I bet you anything that your development of the cookies is wrong. Don't set the `document.cookie` on html. And, if the cookie is dispatched from the PHP Server still using it there; security thank you.